# ado.net entity data model and mysql - problem with UTF8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, ado.net-entity-data-model

I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model in ASP.NET with MySql. I tried many collocation for my databases and tables but so far diacritics (polish) characters are changed.. for example, from ł to l. And this is at query level (I log all query to file on mysql server level). Any ideas? My connection string does not contain any infromation about charset, even if should how to provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the collation of the table or possibly of the entire database to UTF8.